# Data table filtering with Ajax issue in JSF primefaces

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a data table with global filtering. I want to filtered the data. In search criteria I pressed one key based on data is not filtered and Ajax call is wont be terminated still loaded.where I made mistake please suggest me.

Here is my Code:

```xml
<p:dataTable id="dataCall" var="calls" value="#{calllist.mediumCallsModel}" style="font-size: 12px; width: 1000px" widgetVar="callsTable" 
                             emptyMessage="No record found with given criteria"
                             selection="#{calllist.selectedCall}" selectionMode="single"  rows="5" paginator="true" filteredValue="#{callList.filteredDatas}" 
                             paginatorPosition="bottom" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" >
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{calllist.onRowSelect}" update=":MyListForm:showlist: :MyListForm:growl" />  

    <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" listener="#{calllist.onRowUnselect}" update=":MyListForm:growl"/>

    <f:facet name="header">
        <p:outputPanel style="display:block; text-align:right"> 
            <h:outputText value="Search all fields:"/>  
            <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="callsTable.filter()" style="width:150px" />
        </p:outputPanel>
    </f:facet>
    <p:column headerText="Call ID" filterBy="#{calls.callId}" sortBy="#{calls.callId}" filterStyle="display: none; visibility: hidden;">  
        <h:outputText value="#{calls.callId}" />  
    </p:column>  
    <p:column headerText="Created By" filterBy="#{calls.createdBy}" sortBy="#{calls.createdBy}" filterStyle="display: none; visibility: hidden;">  
        <h:outputText value="#{calls.createdBy}" />  
    </p:column>  
    <p:column headerText="Location" filterBy="#{calls.location}" sortBy="#{calls.location}" filterStyle="display: none; visibility: hidden;">  
        <h:outputText value="#{calls.location}" />  
    </p:column> 
    <p:column headerText="Status" filterBy="#{calls.status}" sortBy="#{calls.status}" filterStyle="display: none; visibility: hidden;">  
        <h:outputText value="#{calls.status}" />  
    </p:column> 
    <p:column headerText="Product" filterBy="#{calls.product}" sortBy="#{calls.product}" filterStyle="display: none; visibility: hidden;">  
        <h:outputText value="#{calls.product}" />  
    </p:column>  
    <p:column headerText="Module" filterBy="#{calls.module}" sortBy="#{calls.module}" filterStyle="display: none; visibility: hidden;">  
        <h:outputText value="#{calls.module}" />  
    </p:column>  
    <p:column headerText="Group Assigned" filterBy="#{calls.groupAssigned}" sortBy="#{calls.groupAssigned}" filterStyle="display: none; visibility: hidden;">  
        <h:outputText value="#{calls.groupAssigned}" />  
    </p:column>  
    <p:column headerText="Assigned to" filterBy="#{calls.assignedTo}" sortBy="#{calls.assignedTo}" filterStyle="display: none; visibility: hidden;">  
        <h:outputText value="#{calls.assignedTo}" />  
    </p:column> 
    <p:column headerText="Call creation" filterBy="#{calls.callCreation}" sortBy="#{calls.callCreation}" filterStyle="display: none; visibility: hidden;">  
        <h:outputText value="#{calls.callCreation}" />  
    </p:column>  
</p:dataTable>
```

My Bean:

```
public class CallList{
private List<CallModel> callList = null;
private CallModel selectedCall = new CallModel();
private CallDataModel mediumCallsModel;
private List<CallModel> filteredDatas;
private boolean enableButton;

public CallList() {
    this.enableButton = true;
}

public CallModel getSelectedCall() {
    return selectedCall;
}

public void setSelectedCall(CallModel selectedCall) {
    this.selectedCall = selectedCall;
}

public CallDataModel getMediumCallsModel() {
    getAllList();
    return mediumCallsModel;
}

public void setMediumCallsModel(CallDataModel mediumCallsModel) {
    this.mediumCallsModel = mediumCallsModel;
}

public List<CallModel> getCallList() {
    return callList;

}

public void setCallList(List<CallModel> callList) {
    this.callList = callList;
}
public List<CallModel> getFilteredDatas() {
    return filteredDatas;
}

public void setFilteredDatas(List<CallModel> filteredDatas) {
    this.filteredDatas = filteredDatas;
}
public List<CallModel> getAllList() {
    List<CallHeader> headerList = null;
    List<ProductMaster> productList = null;
    List<StatusMaster> statusList = null;
    List<ModuleMaster> moduleDesc = null;
    List<Time> timeList = null;
    List<PriorityMaster> priorityList = null;
    List<SlaMaster> slaList = null;
    List<SubmoduleMaster> subList = null;
    List<UserMaster> userList=null;
    Session ses = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    try {
        HttpSession sess = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        String userid = (String) sess.getAttribute("userId");
        headerList = ses.createCriteria(CallHeader.class).add(Expression.or(Restrictions.eq("userMaster.userId", userid), Restrictions.eq("assignedId", userid))).list();

        callList = new ArrayList<CallModel>(headerList.size());
        for (Iterator<CallHeader> it = headerList.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            CallHeader callHeader = it.next();

            productList = ses.createCriteria(ProductMaster.class).add(Restrictions.eq("productId", callHeader.getId().getProductId())).list();
            Iterator<ProductMaster> it1 = productList.iterator();
            ProductMaster productMaster = it1.next();

            statusList = ses.createCriteria(StatusMaster.class).add(Restrictions.eq("id.statusId", callHeader.getStatusId())).list();
            Iterator<StatusMaster> it2 = statusList.iterator();
            it2.hasNext();
            StatusMaster statusMaster = it2.next();

            moduleDesc = ses.createCriteria(ModuleMaster.class).add(Restrictions.eq("id.moduleId", callHeader.getModuleId())).list();
            Iterator<ModuleMaster> it3 = moduleDesc.iterator();
            it3.hasNext();
            ModuleMaster moduleMaster = it3.next();

            timeList = ses.createCriteria(Time.class).add(Restrictions.eq("id.callId", callHeader.getId().getCallId())).list();
            Iterator<Time> it4 = timeList.iterator();
            it4.hasNext();
            Time time = it4.next();

            priorityList = ses.createCriteria(PriorityMaster.class).add(Restrictions.eq("id.priorityId", callHeader.getPriorityId())).list();
            Iterator<PriorityMaster> it5 = priorityList.iterator();
            it5.hasNext();
            PriorityMaster priorityMaster = it5.next();

            slaList = ses.createCriteria(SlaMaster.class).add(Restrictions.eq("id.slaId", callHeader.getSlaId())).list();
            Iterator<SlaMaster> it6 = slaList.iterator();
            it6.hasNext();
            SlaMaster slaMaster = it6.next();

            subList = ses.createCriteria(SubmoduleMaster.class).add(Restrictions.eq("id.productId", callHeader.getId().getProductId())).add(Restrictions.eq("id.moduleId", callHeader.getModuleId())).list();
            Iterator<SubmoduleMaster> it7 = subList.iterator();
            it7.hasNext();
            SubmoduleMaster subMaster = it7.next();

            userList=ses.createCriteria(UserMaster.class).add(Restrictions.eq("userId", callHeader.getAssignedId())).list();
            Iterator<UserMaster> it8 = userList.iterator();
            it8.hasNext();
            UserMaster userMaster = it8.next();

            callList.add(new CallModel(callHeader.getId().getCallId(), callHeader.getUserMaster().getFirstName() + " " + callHeader.getUserMaster().getLastName(), callHeader.getUserMaster().getLocation(), statusMaster.getStatusDesc(), productMaster.getProductName(), moduleMaster.getModuleDesc(), callHeader.getGroupMaster().getGroupId(), userMaster.getUserId(), time.getCallCreated(),
                    priorityMaster.getId().getPriorityId(), callHeader.getProposedTime(), callHeader.getAcceptedTime(), callHeader.getActualTime(), callHeader.getCallRelation(), slaMaster.getId().getSlaId(), statusMaster.getId().getStatusId(), productMaster.getProductId(), moduleMaster.getId().getModuleId(), subMaster.getId().getSubmoduleId(), callHeader.getProblemType(),
                    callHeader.getRatingId(), callHeader.getId().getCompanyId(),userMaster.getFirstName()+" "+userMaster.getLastName()));
        }

        mediumCallsModel = new CallDataModel(callList);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        ses.close();
    }
    return callList;
}
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) { }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us types of your `filteredValue` and `value` in `p:datatable`. They have to be of the same type.

Comment: 1. Reduce the problem, remove all the irrelevant columns and attributes which are unecessary to reproduce the error. 2. Post it with the backing bean and the error you get, also your JSF and PF versions. Have a look at [this](http://sscce.org/).